# is float(0) SQL datatype valid?

Tags: sql

I was under the impression that the minimum value for n in float(n) had to be 1.

I've not seen a "float(0)" data type before so I wonder if it's valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question might not be terribly meaningful without specifying an implementation.

In SQL Server, for example, [float's minimum precision is 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx).

> Where n is the number of bits that are
>   used to store the mantissa of the
>   float number in scientific notation
>   and, therefore, dictates the precision
>   and storage size. If n is specified,
>   **it must be a value between 1 and 53**. The default value of n is 53.

In MySQL, on the other hand, `float(0)` is valid syntax, but it doesn't sound terribly meaningful. [From the specification](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html):

> MySQL also supports this optional
>   precision specification, but the
>   precision value is used only to
>   determine storage size. **A precision
>   from 0 to 23 results in a four-byte
>   single-precision FLOAT column**. A
>   precision from 24 to 53 results in an
>   eight-byte double-precision DOUBLE
>   column.

Oracle [has a FLOAT datatype](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm), but it appears to just be an alias for NUMBER, and its minimum precision is 1:

> A subtype of the NUMBER datatype
>   having precision p. A FLOAT value is
>   represented internally as NUMBER.
>   **The precision p can range from 1 to 126 binary digits.** A FLOAT value
>   requires from 1 to 22 bytes.

So you can see that the answer is highly implementation-specific. I'm not sure the ANSI SQL standards specify FLOAT precision. It's possible they do not.

Comment: awesome explanation. I checked what SQL implementation will be used on the server side and it is MySQL. The client will implement SQLite and I suppose in this case the datatype will convert into REAL and automatically get 8 bytes for storage size.

Comment: If the value requires from 1 to 22 bytes, then the range must be from 1 to *176* binary digits.

Comment: That's a good observation... You'll have to take it up with the maintainers of the website from which I copied the quote, though. :)

Answer (score 1):

it isn't valid, because you need to declare the size of the datatype. Obviously can't be zero.

Answer (score 1):

Both Oracle and MS SQL state that minimum value for `float` precision is 1.

This makes sense: it's the number of decimal places you want your floating point number to support. Zero decimal places would mean no value at all.

Answer (score 0):

According to this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx

It is not valid, at least on SQL Server.  0 would represent zero bits, and it's hard to squeeze data into something that has zero storage space.